# How to append CustomQWidget from QVBoxLayout into a QVector

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get every CustomQWidget i added to the layout and insert them into a QVector so i can sort them.

```
void MainWindow::onFilenameClick()
{
    QVector<CustomQWidget*> qv;

    for(int i = 0; i < ui->widgets_layout->count(); i++) {
        QWidget *widget = ui->widgets_layout->itemAt(i)->widget();
        if(widget != nullptr) {
            qv.append(widget);
        }
    }
    std::sort(qv.begin(), qv.end(), sort_by_filename());
    update_ui(qv);
}
```

The problem is that i keep getting the error message

```
no matching member function for call to 'append'
candidate function not viable: cannot convert from base class pointer 'QWidget *' to derived class pointer 'CustomQLabel *const' for 1st argument
candidate function not viable: cannot convert from base class pointer 'QWidget *' to derived class pointer 'CustomQLabel *' for 1st argument
candidate function not viable: cannot convert from base class pointer 'QWidget *' to 'const QVector<CustomQWidget *>' for 1st argument
```

I've already tryed to `static_cast` the CustomQWidget to QWidget but nothing has changed.

```
qv.append(static_cast<QWidget*>(widget));
```

And I also tried with

```
qv.push_back(widget);
qv.insert(i, widget);
```

Here's the **CustomQWidget.h**

```
class CustomQWidget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
...
private:
  Ui::CustomQWidget *ui;
...
};
```

I really don't know what to do, please help me

Answer (score 2):

You state...

> I've already tryed to static_cast the CustomQWidget to QWidget but
> nothing has changed.
>
> ```
> qv.append(static_cast<QWidget*>(widget));
> ```

But why?  `widget` is already of type `QWidget *` and `qv` is declared as...

```
QVector<CustomQWidget *> qv;
```

You need something like (untested)...

```
QVector<CustomQWidget *> qv;

for(int i = 0; i < ui->widgets_layout->count(); ++i) {
    if (auto *custom_widget = dynamic_cast<CustomWidget *>(ui->widgets_layout->itemAt(i)->widget())) {
        qv.append(custom_widget);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, as you're using `Qt`, you can make use of [`qobject_cast`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) rather than `dynamic_cast`...

```
QVector<CustomQWidget *> qv;

for(int i = 0; i < ui->widgets_layout->count(); ++i) {
    if (auto *custom_widget = qobject_cast<CustomWidget *>(ui->widgets_layout->itemAt(i)->widget())) {
        qv.append(custom_widget);
    }
}
```